# Link two docker containers on Windows 10

Tags: windows, docker

I have my mongo container running:

```
docker run --security-opt=seccomp:unconfined -p 27017:27017 -p 28017:28017 --name mong --rm mong --link myapp
```

and my app

```
docker run --rm -ti --security-opt=seccomp:unconfined -p8080:8080 --name myapp --link mong --expose 8080
```

When I run  `docker port myapp`

> 8080/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8080

And `docker port mong` get following:

> 27017/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:27017
>
> 28017/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:28017

However myapp doesn't see mong ports. When I run `docker run --rm -ti --security-opt=seccomp:unconfined -p8080:8080 --name myapp --link mong --expose 8080` with `--net=host` flag myapp starts to see mong container ports, but stops expose 8080.

How to fix it? What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to link two or more containers, you can use [network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#default-networks).

First create a network:

```
$ docker network create --driver bridge dev_network
```

Now run the both container with --net=dev_network

Container 1

```
$ docker run --security-opt=seccomp:unconfined -p 27017:27017 -p 28017:28017 --name mong --rm mong --net=dev_network
```

Container 2

```
docker run --rm -ti --security-opt=seccomp:unconfined -p 8080:8080 --name myapp --net=dev_network
```

You can now access the containers inside the network with container name.

Comment: Will it possible to access myapp on 8080 from hostmachine?

Comment: myapp inside Docker is waiting for connection with mongo on 127.0.0.1

Comment: yes, -p(hostport:containerport) flag defines what port you want to access from host to your container. So if your app was servering webpages on that port, you would use http://localhost:8080/

Comment: In your app source code where you define your mongo ip address, you should use container name instead of ip. As your app is inside the container, it can see other containers with name.